# how to use http query to post data?

Tags: javascript, facebook, http, parameters

I made this below code using facebook graph data and this code stretcher is right.

this is facebook graph data:

```
"hometown": {
    "id": "105988062765295",
    "name": "Sacramento, California"
  }
```

and this is my code:

```
params.hometown = JSON.stringify({
        id: 105988062765295
    });
```

but my below code stretcher is not correct.
Facebook Data:

```
"about": "fffffff"
```

and my code:

```
params.about= { 'fffffff' };
```

how to i write this about code?

If you don't understand, ask me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess:

```
params.about = JSON.stringify({
  id: 'fffffff'
});
```

Comment: someone told me to use `http_query`

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, you cannot update the about text or the hometown with the API. Checkout the available parameter for updating:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/user#Updating

Side note: The ID is a string, as juanlumn pointed out. And setting the about text (if it would be possible) would most likely be like this:

```
params.about = 'fffffff';
```

(string, not object)

I tried updating the about text in the API explorer and got a success message, but it did not really update the text.

Comment: its possible using access token. already i updated profile info, but i can't added about text.

Comment: show me a link to the api explorer where you successfully updated the about text. the api reference says it is not possible.

Comment: i am using on my server.

Comment: how to i create this data `"about": "fffffff"` to `params.about= { 'fffffff' };` this type. only about option not working. hometown option working good.

Comment: i just tried updating the about text with the api explorer. you get a success message, but it does not really update.

Comment: my script has caller class

Comment: someone told me to use http_query(params). i don't understand, how to i do it.

Comment: it is not possible, just try it in the api explorer and see for yourself. read the edited part of my answer.

Comment: can i get your fb id?

Comment: my fb id? i don´t know what you mean, or what you would want to do with my fb id, to be honest.

Comment: i wants to contact with you on Facebook. give me your Facebook profile URL.

Comment: sorry, i don´t do support outside stackoverflow and my facebook profile is reserved for friends only ;) you got everything you need to know in my answer, i believe?